# ITK - How to merge two images

Tags: c++, itk

I'm a beginner in ITK.
I have to merge same dimension ITK images.Is there a filter that can be used to pile images in a stack.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want [image series reader](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1ImageSeriesReader.html), or [join series filter](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1JoinSeriesImageFilter.html), depending whether your 2D images are on disk or in memory.